# What's the emergency number (the 911 equivalent) in Israel?

Tags: israel, emergencies

I'm planning on traveling to Israel at some point or another, and I don't know the emergency services number.

**What is the Israeli equivalent of the American 911, or the British 999?**

Comment: I won't roll back your edit, @JoErNanO, but I don't think that it was necessary. I thought my question was fine in the original version.

Comment: It was fine in the original version, but now it's even better.

Comment: Some discussion on this question in chat, starting around [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20804596#20804596). Join the conversation! cc @MichaelHampton

Comment: @Willeke: Questions do not have "personality" and, indeed, emergencies are not a joke. Anything we can do to correct this misapprehension that joking about emergencies is okay, great!

Comment: I have heard that dialing 911 des work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This Anglo List webpage on the topic](http://anglo-list.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=42&Itemid=107/) carries information on various useful contact numbers in Israel, including emergency numbers:

[image: Emergency Services: Police, 100; Ambulance, 101; Fire, 102; Electric Company, 103; Local Municipality, 106; Bezeq - Information, 144. Dialing 112 from a mobile phone will connect you to the emergency services]

Note [you can also use 112 to contact emergency services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/112_%28emergency_telephone_number%29) in many countries including Israel, in which it is callable from mobile phones only.

Comment: I think 112 is only available from mobile phones there (as mentioned in the picture as well).

Comment: According to [the linked wikipedia article on 112](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/112_%28emergency_telephone_number%29) it's availability from landlines and mobile phones is country-dependent.

Comment: Yes, but I meant in Israel as, in the context of the question, the last sentence of your answer could imply it could be used on landline there.

Comment: Btw, a useful mnemonic for remembering the order of Police, Ambulance, Fire is *People Are Frightening*.